# Password history validation in WSO2 Identity Server 5.2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

How can we validate password history in wso2 Identity Server 5.2.0? Is it OOTB supported or is it require custom extension?

Thanks
Roger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Password history validation is not supported OOTB in IS 5.2.0 released. It will be supported OOTB in 5.3.0 release which will be released in December 2016.

But, If you still need the password history validation for IS 5.2.0 you have to write an extension. [This](http://isurad.blogspot.com/2016/10/password-history-extension-for-wso2.html) blog explains step by step about how to write the extension.

Thanks
Isura

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Comment: Usually the policies for the password history are enforced by the underlying userstore (ActiveDirectory, OpenLDAP , OpenDJ, ...). IMHO having two layers could lead to inconsistency